# How do I fix the problem with forward declaration of struct context when building gcc 4.3.3?

Tags: c++, gcc

When I try to build gcc 4.3.3 from source I get this error
../../.././libjava/prims.cc:193: error: forward declaration of 'struct ucontext'
I have modified every linux-unwind.h so I changed struct ucontext to ucontext_t and still the same error shows up so
Any idea anyone to fix it?

Comment: Why do you want to build such an old version of gcc from source?

Comment: I need it to build a software and also I couldn't find gcc 4.3.3 through apt package manager

Comment: Do you really need this specific version? There are simple ways to get a newer version, e.g. 4.8.5.

Comment: If 4.8.5 is backward compatibility with 4.3.3 then yes otherwise I only need the 4.3.3 version ...

Comment: What do you mean with _backward compatibility_? C++ code is standardized since 1998. If the code is valid C++ code you can use the current version of gcc.

Comment: I mean the the software I'm trying to build uses GCC 4.3.3 and that's why I need this exact version because I don't think I can compile it with the current version of gcc.

Comment: as long as the code is valid C++ in some specific version then the behavior should be the same in any GCC version. Probably the code is in C++03 or C++11 so you need to use `-std=c++11` in newer GCC versions because the default has been changed to C++14 or C++17

Comment: @phuclv "as long as the code is valid C++ in some specific version then the behaviour should be the same in any GCC version." That is only a wish. Even older versions of gcc itself can not be build with current gcc compilers. Some of the problems are: Older compiler did  not reject invalid code, disabling of non c++ features like auto for function parms which was for years possible but not legal c++ code.And also header file names have changed or were in the past included indirectly by including others which current compilers are failing with this code.Theory is perfect, the life is different.

Comment: Have you tried disabling java? You may try to compile with enable-languages=c,c++. If java lib still tries to build, watch out for --disable-lib.xxx for some specific libs. You may have a chance to get rid of the java stuff here.

Comment: Did you try to build the project with the current version of GCC using the flag `-std=c++03`?

Comment: The “forward declaration” isn’t actually an error, but a note along with an error that `ucontext` is incomplete.  Have you arranged to [`#include<ucontext.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/ucontext.h.html)?